# Example of a Non-Abelian Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I was hunting an example of a non-trivial finite group in which

1) All non-trivial normal subgroup are non-abelian.

2) There exists a nontrivial subnormal abelian subgroup.

Is there any hope to find this out?

**Notation**

A subgroup $H$ of a given group $G$ is a *subnormal* subgroup of $G$ if there is a finite chain of subgroups of the group, each one normal in the next, beginning at H and ending at $G$.

Comment: It would be good to include the definition of "subnormal", as it's a simple concept, but probably not a familiar term to everybody.

Comment: This would be an interesting question for infinite groups!

Comment: @DerekHolt In fact I ask below, as a comment to the answer, what will happen in infinite case. It will be better to open a new question or edit this one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a finite group $G$, a subgroup $H\le G$ is contained in the *Fitting subgroup* (denoted $\mathbf{F}(G)$) if and only if $H$ is both subnormal and nilpotent.

If a finite group $G$ has an abelian subnormal subgroup $K\le G$, then $K\le \mathbf{F}(G)$. Because $\mathbf{F}(G)$ is non-trivial, we also have its center is non-trivial: $Z(\mathbf{F}(G))\neq\lbrace1\rbrace$. This is because $\mathbf{F}(G)$ is nilpotent.

But then $Z(\mathbf{F}(G))$ is an abelian normal subgroup of $G$.  Hence no example - as outlined in the question - exists.

Comment: Oh thanks Steve D! 
Can I ask you also an example in the infinite case?

Comment: @W4cc0 Maybe you should ask that as a new question.